# Team Foundation Server mappings disappear

Tags: tfs

Team Foundation Server mappings disappear - that is in Visual Studio 2013: File-> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces I'm trying to add mapping from repository to local folder: I select path in repository; VS automatically add path under local workspace; I press OK. But after reopening Workspaces dialog added mappings are disappeared. What are the possible reasons?

Comment: Visual studio don't ask whether I want to do a get-latest. (I don't remember such request) besides, Now I'm at home and environment in office and now I can't experiment. This is the first time I connected to TFS. Nothing was on my HDD. My coworker created link to server. Maybe it see that added mapping within this outermost path and therefore delete those records? I just try to transfer my Perforce knowledge. depot/a/b ->  a/b will be ignored if depot/a ->  a exist.

Comment: Can it delete mappings record silently? without saying some warnings?

Comment: @jessehouwing: you are write, removing outermost mapping resolved the issue - please add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings in TFS must each point to a unique path and cannot enclose the same on either the source or the target side of things, unless it's a Cloak mapping (which is basically a subtractive mapping).

try removing the `/a` if you are also mapping `/a/b` or vice versa to ensure that each folder is mapped only once.

I would expect a warning or error message when trying to save the mappings, but it sounds like you didn't get them. I'd consider that a bug in the product, you can [file those on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).